# No provider for router in Angular ui

Tags: angular

```
I am getting getting a weird error while running the Angular 8 code. Please find the error log shown below:
```

It is however throwing the error Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

```
When i load pages nothing happens, where I want it to load the content from the corresponding HTML files.
```

I am using 'angular-route' for routing .
 CAn I define a baseurl in my require.config require.config( baseUrl: '' paths : { 'angular' : '../bower_components/angular/angular.min ?

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!

below is the code snippet :



-------------------------------------------------------------
I am getting getting a weird error while running the Angular 8 code. Please find the error log shown below:

Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!

It is however throwing the error Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

When i load pages nothing happens, where I want it to load the content from the corresponding HTML files.
```

I am using 'angular-route' for routing .
 CAn I define a baseurl in my require.config require.config( baseUrl: '' paths : { 'angular' : '../bower_components/angular/angular.min ?

Comment: is it possible to reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com?

Comment: And based on your error message.

you need to add RouterModule in your module

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because there is a problem with one of your unit test files. That is why the error has 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add RouterTestingModule to your test file. Here is a sample code.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [ MyNewComponentComponent ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```